# ng tags input not allowing same text twice to be entered in the text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-tags-input

I am using ng-tags input for autocomplete if the autocomplete bring result of same text , for eg: two results being populated when I type "R", "Rob","Rob" like this.

I have clicked one "Rob" its is in the text box now but when I type again "R" "Rob" is not coming. How to provide the uniqueness for each item in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are unique by default by their text property (here "Rob").
You can change that with the "keyProperty" attribute, setting it to Rob's unique identifier.

```
<tags-input
    ng-model="users"
    key-property="_id"
    display-property="username">
 </tags-input>
```

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api